# CKEditor does not display commas in bulleted lists

Tags: ckeditor

When I add content in a bulleted list using the built in CKEditor in the admin panel of my website, the end result does not show commas between words.
If I go back to the editor, the commas are there.
Could someone help me on this?

Comment: What is the exact HTML? Are you able to provide a working example?

Comment: https://job-center.hu/allasajanlatok/sofor-ar-0475

Comment: Here is a link to one of the pages. Note the line where it says:  Intelligens kommunikatív udvarias személyiség. There should be commas between the first 3 words. Also if you roll down to  Munkavégzés éjszaka, változó munkaidő beosztás mellett it displays the comma there. Check the source code of the page and you'll see some huge spaces where the commas should be. Strange

Comment: I found this in the code. No idea what it means but maybe this is the problem:

Comment: $preferences = explode(',', $jd->Preference);